# JAVA Read Integers form a Text File and Work on the Array Lists

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, file

I have a text file containing the following content:

```
0 12
1 15
2 6
3 4
4 3
5 6
6 12
7 8
8 8
9 9
10 13
```

I want to read these integers from a txt file and save the two columns into two different arrays in Java.

Thanks to *aioobe* for his nice answer for the [first part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277041/read-a-txt-file-containing-two-integer-columns-and-save-into-two-arrays-in-java).

Now I want to develop it in this way:

1. Write a method called `occurrence`, that take a number as an input and write the number of occurrence that this number has.
2. Write another method called `occurrences`, that didn't have any input, but as output it gives the number that has the major number of occurrences (in the second column) in the file.
3. At last, the `Main` program will ask the user to write a number from 1 to 3.

*1=* method that, from an input number (that is the number in the first column) gives back the associated number in the second column.

*2=* the first occurrence method (the one with input)

*3=* the second occurrence method (the one without input)

I wrote the code but there is some errors(about passing the array list to a method) and I need your help about that.
I am a JAVA novice, So if you feel that the code is not appropriate, please make the required changes.
This is my final code:

```
import java.util.*; //importing some java classes
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class list {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Read the text file and store them into two arrays:
        try {
            List<Integer> column1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // Defining an integer Array List
            List<Integer> column2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // Defining an integer Array List

            Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new FileReader("c:/java/data.txt")); // Reading file using Scanner

            while (myfile.hasNext()) {          // Read file content using a while loop
                column1.add(myfile.nextInt());      // Store the first integer into the first array list
                column2.add(myfile.nextInt());      // Store the next integer into the second array list
            }

            myfile.close(); // close the file

            System.out.println("column 1 elements are:\n" + column1);  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
            System.out.println("column 2 elements are:\n" + column2);  // [12, 15, 6, 4, 3, 6, 12, 8, 8, 9, 13]

            //Getting a number(1-3) from user:
            Scanner cases = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-3: "); 
            int num = cases.nextInt();

            switch (num) {
                case 1:
                    Scanner case1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter a number from first column to see how many occurrences it has: "); 
                    int numb = case1.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(column2.get(numb));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    occurrence(column2.toArray());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    occurrences(column2.toArray());
                    break;              
                default: System.out.println("the number is not 1 or 2 or 3!"); 
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {     // we defined it just in the case of error
            e.printStackTrace();    // shows the error
        }

    } // End of MAIN


    public void occurrence(int[] arg) { // Defining occurrence method

        int count = 0;

        //Getting a number from user input:
        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number: "); 
        int number = userin.nextInt();        

        // Finding the occurrences:
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++)
            if (arg[i] == number) count++;

        System.out.println( number + " is repeated " + count + " times in the second column.");
    } // End of occurrence method


    public void occurrences(int[] arg) {    // Defining occurrenceS method

        int max = 0;

        // Finding the maximum occurrences:
        for (int i = 1; i < arg.length; i++)
            if (arg[i] > arg[max]) max = i;
            System.out.println( max + " is the most repeated  number." );
    } // End of occurrenceS method


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing an `Object[]` while your method expects an `int[]`

(note that toArray() returns an Object[])

also, `occurrence()` is an instance method, while main is static, you will need to change `occurrence()` to be a static method as well, or create an instance of list.

so methods signature will be:

```
public static void occurrences(Integer[] arg) 

public static void occurrence(Integer[] arg)
```

and methods calls will be:

```
Integer[] temp = new Integer[column2.size()];
            switch (num) {
                case 1:
                    Scanner case1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter a number from first column to see how many occurrences it has: "); 
                    int numb = case1.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(column2.get(numb));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    occurrence(column2.toArray(temp));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    occurrences(column2.toArray(temp));
                    break;              
                default: System.out.println("the number is not 1 or 2 or 3!"); 
            }
```

p.s. this is not related to your question, but there is a strong java convention that a class name starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer(I also updated the methods):

```
import java.util.*; //By Mehdi Davoudi
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class list {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Read the text file and store them into two arrays:
        try {
            List<Integer> column1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // Defining an integer Array List
            List<Integer> column2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // Defining an integer Array List

            Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new FileReader("c:/java/data.txt")); // Reading file using Scanner

            while (myfile.hasNext()) {          // Read file content using a while loop
                column1.add(myfile.nextInt());      // Store the first integer into the first array list
                column2.add(myfile.nextInt());      // Store the next integer into the second array list
            }

            myfile.close(); // close the file

            System.out.println("column 1 elements are:\n" + column1);  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
            System.out.println("column 2 elements are:\n" + column2);  // [12, 15, 6, 4, 3, 6, 12, 8, 8, 9, 13]

            //Getting a number(1-3) from user:
            Scanner cases = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-3: "); 
            int num = cases.nextInt();

            Integer[] temp = new Integer[column2.size()];

            switch (num) {
                case 1:
                    Scanner case1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter a number from first column to see its pair in second column: "); 
                    int numb = case1.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(column2.get(numb));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Occurrence(column2.toArray(temp));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Occurrences(column2.toArray(temp));
                    break;              
                default: System.out.println("the number is not 1 or 2 or 3!"); 
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {     // we defined it just in the case of error
            e.printStackTrace();    // shows the error
        }

    } // End of MAIN


    public static void Occurrence(Integer[] arg) {  // Defining occurrence method

        int count = 0;

        //Getting a number from user input:
        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number: "); 
        int number = userin.nextInt();        

        // Finding the occurrences:
        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++)
            if (arg[i] == number) count++;

        System.out.println( number + " is repeated " + count + " times in the second column.");
    } // End of occurrence method


    public static void Occurrences(Integer[] ary) { // Defining occurrenceS method
        // Finding the maximum occurrences:
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int a : ary) {
            Integer freq = m.get(a);
            m.put(a, (freq == null) ? 1 : freq + 1);
        }

        int max = -1;
        int mostFrequent = -1;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() > max) {
                mostFrequent = e.getKey();
                max = e.getValue();
            }
        }

        System.out.println( mostFrequent + " is the most repeated  number in second column." );
    } // End of occurrenceS method


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer [BufferedReader](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/readFile/index.html). Read it line by line and use String.split() method to get the column elements.

Comment: this is not related to his question in any way. there's nothing wrong with his file handling.